# inline-block nowrap resize issue

Tags: css

I have being trying to make a nowrap navigation with CSS however when I hover over  the parent list for lack of a better description jumps
HTML

```css
 html { 
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    ul li{
        list-style:none;
    }
    nav{
        margin: 0 -9999rem;
        padding: 0.25rem 9999rem;
        height:40px;
        background-color:white;
      overflow:hidden;
    }

    nav .user-nav{
        position:absolute;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    nav .user-nav > li{
          display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }

    nav .user-nav li a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:black;
    }

    nav .user-nav li a:hover{
        color:red;
    }
    nav .user-nav > .interact li{
        display:none;
        background-color:white;
        padding:10px;
    }
    nav .user-nav > .interact:hover li{
        display:block;
    }

    nav .user-nav > .interact li:hover{
        color:red;
    }
```

```html
<nav>
        <ul class="user-nav">
            <li><a href="">Reccent reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Reccent addtions</a></li>
            <li class="interact"><a href="">Login/Register</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

I added it to a fiddle below

https://jsfiddle.net/23e5aLp2/

I initially done it with a float however since reading a bit more I found inline-block is the better option, the problem is as I mentioned the parent list seems to jump when hover over the drop down menu

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6guLu3vL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `<ul>` inside of `.interact` positioned absolute, like:

```
.interact ul {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```css
.interact ul {
  position: absolute;
}

html { 
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    ul li{
        list-style:none;
    }
    nav{
        margin: 0 -9999rem;
        padding: 0.25rem 9999rem;
        height:40px;
        background-color:white;
      overflow:hidden;
    }

    nav .user-nav{
        position:absolute;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
    nav .user-nav > li{
          display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }

    nav .user-nav li a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:black;
    }

    nav .user-nav li a:hover{
        color:red;
    }
    nav .user-nav > .interact li{
        display:none;
        background-color:white;
        padding:10px;
    }
    nav .user-nav > .interact:hover li{
        display:block;
    }

    nav .user-nav > .interact li:hover{
        color:red;
    }
```

```html
<nav>
        <ul class="user-nav">
            <li><a href="">Reccent reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Reccent addtions</a></li>
            <li class="interact"><a href="">Login/Register</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `inline-table` or `inline-block` for class `nav .user-nav  li`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23e5aLp2/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Its because the list items are block elements, thus making the container bigger in size when they spawn in. Make the dropdown items absolute and your problem will be solved.

http://prntscr.com/ddn5xe

http://prntscr.com/ddn5gv

As for the nav question; a text-align: justify solution might work, or a flexbox solution. Try googling around for "nav justify text" or "nav flexbox" and you'll find a pletora of solutions.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that

Comment: There's a lot of solutions on this one. I'd suggest looking at a few of them and see what fits best. You could for example also align the other nav items (that jump down) to the top.

Comment: Looking at a few now, I always preferred PHP but time to stretch my legs a little and learn some more

Answer (score 0):

Actually what is happening is that the inline block works well if you add same content in all inline block elements but as they are block elements their default settings will wrap the div around the content inside it. To make sure the content is aligned correctly in line, you need to specifically assign content alignment properties in the css of the inline-block elements.

The simplest solution in your scenario is just add `vertical-align:top;` to the `nav .user-nav > li` class or the element with the `display:inline-block;` property and the problem will be resolved.

Hope this helps.